# Add GET Parameters to URL in Wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I would like to add GET Parameters to my wordpress pages url like so the page url would be like:

mywebsite.com/parent/mypage?social=facebook

But I cannot manage to do so :(
Any help would be much appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A GET parameter isn't included in quotes in the URL - omit them

Comment: my bad, i took them off

Comment: Apparently, there is a plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-params/